# Where should I start if I want to design a new type of aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, engineering

I want to conduct informational interviews with individuals who work in aviation/aerospace to understand the various roles involved in designing a new aircraft and bringing it to market.

I'm curious if I should start with the FAA, perhaps an engineer, or an aircraft designer.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. The question you're asking is an interesting one, and the *overview* of a good answer to it could cover a chapter or two, with a more complete answer filling a full textbook. That makes it far too broad to be a good fit for the Stack Exchange "Question & Answer" model, which works for questions that can be answered in a post of a few or several paragraphs, rather than chapters. When you have more focused questions about more specific aspects of your project, this may be a good place to get them answered, so please feel free to ask those questions here.

Comment: What is the nature of the course? Is associated with business? Finance? Engineering? Are these the aspects that they are considering with that project?

Comment: I would think the first place I will start would be what the purpose of this aircraft is going to be, and what kind of a performance profile is required to meet customer needs.

Comment: When you say ‘new type of aircraft’ do you mean a new model or a new principle of flight?

Answer (score 2):

You start by setting up a team of people who know how to set up a team of people who can design and build an aircraft.

And yes, that sounds like a troll answer but it isn't. You're not going to do this alone, and you seem to not know who you need to do it so you need to find people who know about such things.